# Why won't my data show up in my Plotly map?

Tags: python, plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Istackz/OOSE-TEST/master/data_file.csv')
df['id'] = df['type'] + '' + df['url'] + ', ' + df['created_at'] + '' + 'location: ' + df['description']+ df['how_to_apply']\
        + df['company_logo'].astype(str)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(

    mode='markers',


))

fig.update_layout(

    title='Github JOBS',
    geo_scope='usa',)
fig.show()
```

My data such as ("location, id,created_at ect.) does not show up on my USA Map. The Map should display with all of the separate categories in CSV file when hovered upon on the location in the US MAP.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: go.Scattergeo doesn't have any data.